# java clickable-through non transparent Component in a transparent clickable-through jframe

Tags: java, linux, swing, transparent, always-on-top

OS = Ubuntu; JDK = 1.7.0_10

General:

What I want is something commonly available as desktop widget (e.g. annotate for compiz or gromit), is there a way to do it in Java?

I want to create one jframe or window to be full-screen, transparent, clickable-though and always on top.
Inside the jframe I want to add/remove components (text, images, rectangles..) to be positioned on a specific point of the screen. Those component should be non-trasparent and always on top. If possible they should allow to click through.

Example: 
I have several app opened on my desktop.
I want to automatically draw a box around window which is on focus drawing a rectangle around the window, the area of the rectangle should be transparent and clickable-thsough in order to allow me to use my application.

Problems:

I can create a transparent frame which stays on top but is not clickable-through, but The component what I will ad to the frame will be in any case transparent.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
frame.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
frame.setLocation(0,0);
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
//frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", false);     //apple
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(frame, 0.0f);
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello NOT transparent label");
label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
frame.getContentPane().add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I can make the frame transparent and clickable-through by setting the IconImage with a transparent image loaded from URL. 
This works if the image is loaded from an URL but not if I load the image from a local file (why?!?). 
Also in this case, when I add a component to the frame is not displayed.

```
try {
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/xtZK0.png")));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I tried to add a JFXPanel but no success, I tried adding the component to the GlassPane but no success..

After one week of intensive tests and search I hope someone can give me a solution or the right hint.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt Java is the right language for this.